# Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I'm a beginner and I was using Visual Studio Code and when I open the terminal to run the necessary (i was working with docker and had to write docker-composer up and don't work because of it) for the docker thing and i received:

```
`Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes. If you want to re-enable it, run 'Import-Module PSReadLine'.`
```

I tried with put Blind Acces on 0, but it didn't work, aside, idk why even if I put that on 0, then appears again on 1 when i reboot and I'm stucked (I'm doing configurations with docker, postgresql and PGAdmin on my Windows 11, ofc).

I just want to finalize my docker-postgres and pgadmin config

Comment: Warnings aren't errors -- they don't stop things from working, they just might mean something works a little less well. Is there a reason you care about this? (Yes, the powershell command line is a little less pleasant for a human to interact with without PSReadLine, but that doesn't matter for using pgadmin)

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Visual SourceSafe?

Comment: Thank you so much for the correction, the thing was that it didn't let me continue, but at least I found a way. Thanks.

Comment: If you described _in the question_ what the symptom (other than printing a warning) that "didn't let [you] continue", that would be more actionable. Anyhow -- consider using the _Add an Answer_ button (which may be called "Post Your Answer" or such) to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows PowerShell ISE open a New Script and put the next:

```
public static class ScreenReaderFixUtil
{
    public static bool IsScreenReaderActive()
    {
        var ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
            int hr = Interop.SystemParametersInfo(
                Interop.SPI_GETSCREENREADER,
                sizeof(int),
                ptr,
                0);

            if (hr == 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            return Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr) != 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SetScreenReaderActiveStatus(bool isActive)
    {
        int hr = Interop.SystemParametersInfo(
            Interop.SPI_SETSCREENREADER,
            isActive ? 1u : 0u,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Interop.SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

        if (hr == 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }

    private static class Interop
    {
        public const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x0002;

        public const int SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 0x0046;

        public const int SPI_SETSCREENREADER = 0x0047;

        [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
            uint uiAction,
            uint uiParam,
            IntPtr pvParam,
            uint fWinIni);
    }
}'

if ([ScreenReaderFixUtil]::IsScreenReaderActive()) {
    [ScreenReaderFixUtil]::SetScreenReaderActiveStatus($false)
}``
```

Comment: This is just a botched, uncredited copy of https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11751#issuecomment-600120959